# CLGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation error -8

Tags: ios, swift

I simulated a foreign location，and use `CLGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation(_ location:, completionHandler:)`,but i got an error - `[Client] Geocode error: Error Domain=GEOErrorDomain Code=-8 "(null)"`

Comment: Show us your code that you are trying

Comment: It may be because you are trying to get the address of the location which is not available. Try with other latitude and longitude and see the result.

Comment: [Error 8](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/clerror.code/1423587-geocodefoundnoresult) means the reverseGeocoder couldn't find a location.
Error8: The geocode request yielded no result.

Comment: Never success@Dávid Pásztor

Answer (score 0):

When i faced same problem

> Geocoding requests are rate-limited for each app, so making too many
>   requests in a short period of time may cause some of the requests to
>   fail. When the maximum rate is exceeded, the geocoder passes an error
>   object with the value network to your completion handler.

[Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/clgeocoder/1423621-reversegeocodelocation)

Comment: then also see this :https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/clerror?language=objc
because You get this error in case Apple's Geocoder knows nothing about provided address.