# Geocode error: Error Domain=GEOErrorDomain Code=-8 "(null)"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I run that code I get the error!

```
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

    let userLoc = CLLocation(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude )

    for i in 0 ..< streetArray.count{

        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(self.streetArray[i]) { (placemarks, error) in

            let location = placemarks?.first?.location

            let destLoc = CLLocation(latitude: (location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (location?.coordinate.longitude)! )

            let distanceInMeters = userLoc.distance(from: destLoc)

            self.distanceArray.append(distanceInMeters)

            print(self.distanceArray)

        }

    }

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}
```

Any ideas why I get the error?

The error appears as Thread 1: EXC_Breakpoint ..

The line that the error appeared is

```
 let destLoc = CLLocation(latitude: (location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (location?.coordinate.longitude)! )
```

Comment: on what line of your code does that error appear?

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44281862/3901620

Comment: `Error -8` means the `Geocoder` couldn't find a location. So check the values of your `latitude` and `longitude`

Comment: In that line you use optional chaining, but then force-unwrap the result. Why? Make up your mind, use one or the other. If `location` was `nil`, that would crash. Use `guard let location = placemarks?.first?.location else { continue }`